# Analysis of variables of varying numbers

Tags: st.statistics, ne.neural-evol

I work with amino acid sequences and I want to use a self-made model to tell me something about it, let's call it f(seq). Now I want to know the contribution of every position in the sequence onto the model. E.q. My question is what is the importance/effect of amino acid A occurring at position I in the sequence with respect to the model?

How do I visualize something like that?

I want to use my model also on several sequences of differing lengths. Somehow this throws a monkey wrench into my plans of using a neural net...

My question is simple yet I did not find anything about it. Pointers would be appreciated. Or any comment you might have. This whole idea of mine is pretty unfinished and I don't really know yet what I want. So feel free to criticize, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: What kind of model do you have, in particular deterministic or probabilistic?

How would you like to measure contribution? I can imagine using an independence measure if every position and $f(seq)$ are treated as random variables. If $f(seq)$ is independent of $seq[i]$ the $i$th symbol does not yield a contribution.

Comment: You are more likely to find answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question.

Comment: the best thing would be to keep the model abstract. but it will be a probabilistic one probably. I will look into independence measures (: However i think the sequence positions should not be regarded as independent. I would like to find some pattern or sth that has a bigger contribution than a single amino acid.

Comment: i will repost the question at stats.stackexchange and pool the answers. thanks

Comment: Question is too vague to be answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"My question is what is the importance/effect of amino acid A occuring at position I in the sequence with respect to the model?"

I suggest [Monotony and Surprise](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.4858&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Apostolico for the modeling of importance of words appearing at certain positions, or in certain patterns.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: This link is behind a paywall I think, but is a less technical explanation of the approach.  http://www.springerlink.com/content/nn13140321803528/fulltext.pdf